# Difference between "new Date().valueOf()" and Date().valueOf()"

Tags: javascript

Why are the two expressions below returning different results?

```
Date().valueOf()
"Fri Feb 07 2014 16:03:34 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

new Date().valueOf()
1391807020802

Date().toString()
"Fri Feb 07 2014 16:09:21 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

new Date().toString()
"Fri Feb 07 2014 16:09:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Comment: Look at the *immediate result* of `Date()` and `new Date()`. Then you can answer your own question. (Refer to the documentation along the *observed types* as appropriate.)

Comment: thanks. >>>typeof(Date()) "string" >>> typeof(new Date()) "object"

Answer (score 6):

`Date()` returns a timestamp formatted as a string.

`new Date()` returns a `Date` instance.

Instances of the `Date` constructor have values that convert to numbers, which is why `new Date().valueOf()` returns a number. Strings are simply strings, so when you call `Date().valueOf()` you get the same string result.